# Eclipse - When to choose a View vs. Property vs. Perspective vs. etc

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am wondering if there are definitions for when to develop different plugins for eclipse. For instance, I am wanting to create something that can either be a wizard in eclipse or a property in eclipse. Both the property and wizard would be associated with a project. Is there a common practice for when to do one over the other? Or is this just by preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no hard rules for which approach to choose, but here are a few things to consider:

1. User experience: Think about how the user would want to make the change, what would be easiest/most intuitive for them.
2. Applying the change: With a wizard you'd be collecting data up front, possibly over multiple pages, and only applying the change on clicking Finish. With properties the changes will generally be to single fields and applied immediately.
3. Undo: Do you want the change to be undo-able? If so a property sheet may be a better fit. Changes through a wizard could still go on the undo stack, but it would be more unusual.
4. Complexity: If there are multiple fields to change or the user needs guidance in making the change a wizard might be more appropriate.
5. When the change is made: If it's data that you want to configure on a new project, but also want to change later, it might be better to include it both in the New Project wizard and a property sheet.